# Using React Router with different tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React Router has a Link component with generates an HTML `<a>` element.

I need to generate an `<area href=... >`.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can have `Link` as child to your component, it will give you desired behavior.

Comment: This way didn't worked. I'm accepting your answear in relation to the onClick part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have `Link` as child to your component.

```
<area>
    <Link 
       to={'/path/to/somehwhere}'}>
       Click Me
    </Link>
</area>
```

Or you can specify a `onclick` event handler on `area` and use `hashHistory` or `browserHistory` from `react-router` to manually navigate user to desired location.

```
<area onClick={handleClick}>
     // your code here
</area>
```

and `handleClick` will have

```
handleClick = (): void => {
    hashHistory.push('/path/to/somehwhere'); // or browserHistory
}
```

In these both ways you can achieve your desired behavior. You can read more about navigating users programmatically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router).

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that you can also wrap your whole component inside `Link`.

```
<Link to='/path/to/somewhere'>
     <area />
</Link>
```

Comment: With Link inside area: area is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: You can register an `onClick` handler. `<area onClick={handleClick} />`